# Demonstrating non-differentiability with absolute value equations.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, absolute-value

I have a function $f(x)=|x^2-4|$.

I am able to use the following definition of absolute value to show that $f(x)$ is non-differentiable at $x=\pm2$
$|x| =
\begin{cases}
x, & x\geq0 \\
-x, & x<0
\end{cases} $.

When I use that definition I find that $\lim \limits_{x \to -2-} f'(x)=-4$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to -2+} f'(x)=4$

However, I am not able to show that with the following definition for the absolute value:
$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$.

$|x^2-4|=\sqrt{(x^2-4)^2}$

$\lim \limits_{x \to -2} \frac{\sqrt{(x^2-4)^2}-\sqrt{((-2)^2-4)^2}}{x-(-2)}$

$=\lim \limits_{x \to -2} \frac{\sqrt{(x^2-4)^2}-0}{x+2}$

$=\lim \limits_{x \to -2} \frac{(x^2-4)^2}{(x+2)^2}$

$=\lim \limits_{x \to -2} \frac{(x+2)^2(x-2)^2}{(x+2)^2}$

$=\lim \limits_{x \to -2} (x-2)^2$

$=((-2)-2)^2=16$

I have bad fundamentals. So, I apologize for missing something basic. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes:

First, when you write
$$
\sqrt{(x^2 - 4)^2} = x^2 - 4 
$$
in the numerator of your calculation, you are assuming that
$$
\sqrt{u^2} = u, 
$$
which is only true if $u \geq 0$.

The actual formula (which you of course know) is:
$$
\sqrt{u^2} = |u|. 
$$

Second, you replace a rational expression by its square at the next step, but of course, they're not the same thing.

Does this help?

Comment: Oh. So, is there an equation that holds true for when $u<0$? Or does it have to be a piecewise function?

I squared the entire fraction. So, that should allow me to square the numerator and the denominator. Is that not correct?

The first part definitely helps me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$\begin{array}{cccl}f:
&\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow& \mathbb{R}\\&x&\longmapsto& |x^{4}-4|\end{array}$$ To see whether $f$ is differentiable at $-2$ on $\mathbb{R}$, we compute the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to -2; x\in \mathbb{R}-\{-2\}}\frac{f(x)-f(-2)}{x-(-2)}=\lim_{x\to -2; x\in \mathbb{R}-\{-2\}}\frac{|x^{2}-4|-|(-2)^{2}-4|}{x+2}=\lim_{x\to -2; x\in \mathbb{R}-\{-2\}}\frac{|x^{2}-4|}{x+2}
\end{align}

- Just by definition of absolute value $x\mapsto |x|=\begin{cases} x,\quad x\geqslant 0,\\ -x,\quad x<0\end{cases}$. We can take left limits and right limits and we can see that limits they are not same. Indeed, $$\lim_{x\to -2; x\in \left]-2,+\infty\right[}f(x)=+4,\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to -2; x\in \left]-\infty,-2\right[}f(x)=-4.$$
  Therefore, $f$ is non-differentiable at $-2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. What is about if one restrics $f$ to $[-2,+\infty[$ or to $]-\infty,-2]$? Does it $f|_{[-2,+\infty[}$ or $f|_{]-\infty,-2]}$ differerentiable at $-2$?
- On the other hand, using the fact $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\sqrt{x^{2}}=|x|$, then
  $$\lim_{x\to -2; x\in \mathbb{R}-\{-2\}}\frac{|x^{2}-4|}{x+2}=\lim_{x\to -2; x\in \mathbb{R}-\{-2\}}\frac{\sqrt{(x^{2}-4)^{2}}}{x+2}$$
  and here $\underline{\text{you need to see the left limits and right limits again}}$ and we can see that limits they are not same. Indeed,
  $$\lim_{x\to -2; x\in \left]-2,+\infty\right[}f(x)\not= \lim_{x\to -2; x\in \left]-\infty,-2\right[}f(x).$$

In your approach when you use the fact $\sqrt{x^{2}}=|x|$ for all real number $x$ you assume that the sub-radical quantity is non-negative, that is a problem. The best approach to this problem is to work directly with the definition of absolute value.

Comment: I see. The second "definition" of absolute value doesn't work for negative values of x. I thought both of these were definitions of absolute value. So, the first piecewise function is the one true definition of the absolute value? Thank you!

Comment: The definition usual of absolute value is $f:\mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}$, $x\mapsto |x|:=\begin{cases} x,\quad x\geqslant 0,\\ -x,\quad x<0\end{cases}$. Now, notice if $x\geqslant 0$, then $\sqrt{x^{2}}=x$ and if $x<0$, then $\sqrt{x^{2}}=-x$. Combining both cases we have $\sqrt{x^{2}}=|x|$ (just using the definition of absolute value).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you. It's a typo. I fixed.